# ng-repeat only to specific div elements

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS in my application. I am trying to display events using AngularJS bootstrap calendar. The problem is I am not able to specify ***ng-repeat*** at once.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="ce-second-side">
    <div class="ce-each-time">
    <input type="text" ng-model="range1" ng-click="select(range1)" readonly>
    <span data-ng-repeat="notify in notifiesOnDate" data-ng-
    if="notify.startTime=='12:00 Hrs'">{{notify.employeeName}}</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="range2" ng-click="select(range2)" readonly>
    <span data-ng-repeat="notify in notifiesOnDate" data-ng-
    if="notify.startTime=='12:30 Hrs'">{{notify.employeeName}}</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see i am specifying ng-repeat for two input types. But i want to specify ***ng-repeat*** only once in the main div tag with `class="ce-second-side"`.
But i dont want ***ng-repeat*** to apply to input type tag. I want it to apply only to `{{notify.employeeName}}`. 
Can anyone tell how to apply ***ng-repeat*** only for `{{notify.employeeName}}` and not for input tag but I want to do ***ng-repeat*** in main div tag only once?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `groupBy` filter. Luckily `angular.filter` module has it, so you just need to import its script. Here is a demo of how it works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.17/angular-filter.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


    <div ng-repeat="(key,values) in notifiesOnDate | groupBy:'startTime'">

      <div ng-show="key=='12:00 Hrs'"><input type="text" ng-model="range1" ng-click="select(range1)" readonly></div>
      <div ng-show="key=='12:30 Hrs'"><input type="text" ng-model="range2" ng-click="select(range2)" readonly></div>

      <div ng-repeat="notify in values">
        {{notify.employeeName}}
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.range1 = "12:00am - 12:30am";
      $scope.range2 = "12:30am - 01:00am";

      $scope.notifiesOnDate = [
      {"startTime" : "12:00 Hrs", "employeeName" : "AAA"},
      {"startTime" : "12:00 Hrs", "employeeName" : "BBB"},
      {"startTime" : "12:00 Hrs", "employeeName" : "CCC"},
      {"startTime" : "12:30 Hrs", "employeeName" : "111"},
      {"startTime" : "12:30 Hrs", "employeeName" : "222"},
      {"startTime" : "12:30 Hrs", "employeeName" : "333"},
      ];

      $scope.select = function(val) {
        $scope.display = angular.copy(val);
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<div class="ce-second-side">
   <div class="ce-each-time" data-ng-repeat="notify in notifiesOnDate">
     <input type="text" ng-model="range1" ng-click="select(range1)" readonly>
     <span data-ng-if="notify.startTime=='12:00 Hrs'">{{notify.employeeName}}</span>
     <input type="text" ng-model="range2" ng-click="select(range2)" readonly>
     <span data-ng-if="notify.startTime=='12:30 Hrs'">{{notify.employeeName}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to apply ng repeat to input tag, but in your code you included both input tag and span.

Comment: You can take them out of the div.